# Extend geom_rect to edge of geom_tile?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a heatmap with geom_tile. I also want to bring attention to a specific area by drawing a rectangle around the zone. However, I would like to extent the red rectangle to the edges of d6 and d1 (in the following example).

```
df <- data.frame(
  sensor_date = rep(seq(from = as.Date("2018/3/4"), to = as.Date("2018/3/6"), "days"), each = 6),
  depth_class = as.factor(rep(c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6"), 3)),
  freq = rnorm(18, 10, 4)
)


df_rect <- data.frame(
  sensor_date = as.Date(c(rep("2018/3/5", 6)), format = "%Y/%m/%d"),
  depth_class = c("d0")
)


ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = sensor_date, y = depth_class, fill = freq)) +
  geom_rect(
    data = df_rect, linewidth = 1, colour = "red", fill = NA, alpha = 0.2,
    aes(
      xmin = min(sensor_date - .5),
      xmax = max(sensor_date + .5),
      ymin = min("d6"),
      ymax = max("d1")
    )
  )
```

[image: plot1]

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similiar to what you have done for your dates, convert `depth_class` to a numeric and add -/+ .5. As `depth_class` is already a `factor` you could convert to a numeric using `as.numeric(depth_class)` (Thanks to @Dasr for pointing that out).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

set.seed(123)

df_rect <- df |>
  filter(sensor_date == as.Date("2018-03-05")) |>
  group_by(sensor_date) |>
  summarise(
    ymin = min(as.numeric(depth_class)) - .5,
    ymax = max(as.numeric(depth_class)) + .5
  )

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = sensor_date, y = depth_class, fill = freq)) +
  geom_rect(
    data = df_rect,
    linewidth = 1, colour = "red", fill = NA, alpha = 0.2,
    aes(
      xmin = min(sensor_date - .5),
      xmax = max(sensor_date + .5),
      ymin = ymin,
      ymax = ymax
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Can you not directly convert to numeric within the ymin/ymax argument?

Comment: @Dasr Yep. You are right. I missed that `depth_class` is already a factor.

Comment: I have a bit of an issue. Because I have multiple rectangles when I take xmin, ymin of the range then they all basically become one big rectangle. What is the best way to get around this. I mean, I could make a function that calculates separate boundaries for each of the rectangles but it seems really complicated to achieve something relatively simple.

Comment: I thought something like ```group = sensor_date``` but doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Hm. The group aes is not necessary. Create a dataframe where each row corresponds to one rectangle, i.e. in my code df_rect is a dataframe with one row, hence one rectangle is drawn. And if you want to draw a rectangle for let's say d1 to d3, then of course you have to do `ymin = 1 - .5, ymax = 3 + .5`. For more help on what's the best or easiest approach to create `df_rect` in this case I'm afraid we need some more information and a more general example.

Comment: But how do I index each row of the data.frame within the ymin and ymax call? because in your comment above you've just written it. Sorry, I can provide a more complex example if you want. But basically imagine there are 20 days and 5 days are fully highlighted (similar to above). Thus, the ymin/ymax remain the same, but the xmin,xmax have to be independent for each rectangle as otherwise they all merge.

Comment: In that case add a column with xmin and xmax to the dataset, e.g. for your example data we could add `xmin = min(sensor_date) - .5` and `xmax = max(sensor_date) + .5` to the summarise. Then use `xmin=xmin`... in geom_rect.